# firebase_database - module ‘firebase_database’ not found while creating iOS build. (Flutter)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this package version firebase_database: ^3.0.6

others firebase packages version as below :
firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
firebase_database: ^3.0.6
firebase_storage: ^3.1.6

**fatal error: module 'firebase_database' not found**

```
I am using this package version firebase_database: ^3.0.6

others firebase packages version as below :
firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
firebase_database: ^3.0.6
firebase_storage: ^3.1.6



>  fatal error: module 'firebase_database' not found
> 
>     /Users/krunal.thakkar/workspace/personal/projects/tribe/trxbe-app/trxbe/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:34:9:
> fatal error: module 'firebase_database' not found @import
> firebase_database; ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. note:
> Using new build system note: Building targets in parallel note:
> Planning build note: Constructing build description Encountered error
> while building for device.
```